# RecyclerView + NestedScrollView + BottomSheetBehavior = bad performance?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet, nestedrecyclerview

Using `Support library 27.1.1`. I have a `NestedScrollView` with [BottomSheetBehavior](https://www.androidauthority.com/bottom-sheets-707252/). Inside the bottom sheet layout I have `LinearLayout` with a header view at the top, then a `RecyclerView` at the bottom. The RecyclerView is populated with 10-20 custom views with heavy `onDraw` methods.

The whole idea of having a RecyclerView was to avoid inflating these views, as they are quite heavy to render. I want these views to render as soon as they are scrolled into view (dragging the bottom sheet header). The problem is that **all children of the `RecyclerView` are inflated/rendered immediately.** I thought I could stop this from happening using a custom `LinearLayoutManager` but haven't succeeded thus far.

There are a few sources on the net, discussing this particular problem. However, in my case there are a few things that change the conditions.

1. The `RecyclerView` is used along with the `BottomSheetBehavior`. With a height of `0dp` the sheet cannot be opened!
2. The height of the custom views is known to be *half* the view width.
3. Support Library 27.1.1 or later is targeted (most discussions on the net consider v23.2).

**Q:** Is it possible to get the `RecyclerView` to recycle its views when put inside a `NestedScrollView` with `BottomSheetBehavior`? Or would it be easier to somehow prevent the heavy `onDraw` in the child views?